# Problem in using vector in birthday cake candles hacker rank problem

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

firstly I tried the problem using vector but I got the segmentation fault.

This is my code using vector...

```
int main()
vector<int>v;
int n,x;
cin>>n;
int size=v.size();
int max_c=v[0];
int count_max=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>x;
    v.push_back(x);
}
for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
    if(max_c<v[i]){
        max_c=v[i];
    }
} 
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(v[i]==max_c){
        count_max+=1;
    }
}
cout<<count_max;
return 0;
}
```

Then I try the same problem using array then my program successfully compiled
This is my code using array..

```
int main()
{
int n;
cin>>n;
long v[n];    
long max_c=v[0];
int count_max=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>v[i];
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(max_c<v[i]){
        max_c=v[i];
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
     if(v[i]==max_c){
        count_max+=1;
    }
}
cout<<count_max;
return 0;
}
```

Please tell me what is the problem in my first code(using vector)?

Comment: `int max_c=v[0];` invokes *undefined behavior*  because your vector is empty

Comment: There is a problem with your second code. `cin>>n; long v[n];` -- This is not valid C++.  Stop using online competition coding sites to learn C++.  Those sites assume you know the language you are using well enough to never make errors as you are making now with the language.

Comment: Please post a [mre]. Your first code has syntax errors.

Comment: I guess you mean `v.resize(n);`

Comment: In  the first code delete `int size=v.size();` and move `int max_c=v[0];` to after you input. You should check first if the v is empty before continuing the rest of the loop

Comment: Your second code  undefined behaviour, from reading the indeterminate `v[0]`.  You were just having bad luck when that indeterminate value happened to be something that made your code appear to work.

Comment: The second code is not standard C++ anyway. The program is ill-formed. It doesn't make sense to even talk about undefined behaviour here.

Comment: When you are referring to online problem please provide link to description of the problem or at least provide a full description of problem you are solving. Just so we could know what this code should do (it may do something else than it actually does ).

Answer (score 1):

Read the comments below for the first code that you provided:

```
int main()          // missing opening brace {
vector<int>v;
int n,x;
cin>>n;
int size=v.size();   // what's the point here, vector is empty at this point
int max_c=v[0];      // vector is empty at this point, undefined behavior
int count_max=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>x;
    v.push_back(x);
}
for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
    if(max_c<v[i]){
        max_c=v[i];
    }
} 
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(v[i]==max_c){
        count_max+=1;
    }
}
cout<<count_max;
return 0;
}
```

For second code that you provided, read the comments:

```
int main()
{
int n;
cin>>n;
long v[n];          // not standard C++, GCC may support this though - not sure  
long max_c=v[0];
int count_max=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>v[i];
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(max_c<v[i]){
        max_c=v[i];
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
     if(v[i]==max_c){
        count_max+=1;
    }
}
cout<<count_max;
return 0;
}
```

Solution:

You can resize the `vector` during declaration by passing `n` to the constructor after taking `n` as input.

Also, you don't need a separate loop to find max element. Just use the same loop you use for input into vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v(n);
    int max_c = INT_MIN;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> v[i];
        max_c = max(max_c, v[i]);
    }
    
    int count_max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (v[i] == max_c) {
            count_max++;
        }
    }
    cout << count_max;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should point out the issue in OPs code, not only correct code

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, I have edited my answer. Hope I have covered most of the points.

Comment: @Arty, oh yeah. Thanks for pointing out :-) Made the edits.

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that you're trying to access the 1st element of the empty vector `v` when you wrote:

```
int max_c=v[0]; //since v is empty vector, this is undefined behavior
```

The above statement leads to **undefined behavior**.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

The program may also produce **segmentation fault** which is what happens in your case.

So the **first step** to make the program correct would be to **remove undefined behavior**.

##### Solution

To **solve** this problem you can create a vector of size `n` after taking the value of `n` from user, as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin>>n;
    
    //create vector of size n
    std::vector<int> v(n);
    
    //take input from user
    for(int& element: v){
        std::cin>>element;
    }
    
    int max_c=v.at(0);
    int count_max=0;
    //find max
    for(int i=1;i<v.size();i++){ //note i starts from 1 instead of 0 now 
        if(max_c<v[i]){
            max_c=v[i];
        }
    } 
    std::cout<<"maximum is: "<<max_c<<std::endl;
    //count max occurence
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(v[i] == max_c){
            count_max+=1;
        }
    }
    
    std::cout<<"occurence is: "<<count_max;
    return 0;
}
```

Note you can also **get rid of** one of the for loops in the above code by merging the 1st and 2nd for loop, as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <climits> //for INT_MIN
int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin>>n;
    
    //create vector of size n
    std::vector<int> v(n);
    
    int max_c = INT_MIN;
    
    //find max
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){  
        std::cin >> v[i];
        if(max_c<v[i]){//you can also use max_c = std::max(max_c,v[i]) instead of this if block
            max_c=v[i];
        }
    }
    
    int count_max=0;
    std::cout<<"maximum is: "<<max_c<<std::endl;
    //count max occurence
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(v[i] == max_c){
            count_max+=1;
        }
    }
    
    std::cout<<"occurence is: "<<count_max;
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Comment: Hey, the second loop isn't needed actually, the find max operation can be done in the first loop itself.

Comment: @kiner_shah Added that also at the end of my answer.